# UITableView is not displaying data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I took an `UIViewController`. Then brought a `TableView` into it. And then a `TableViewCell` in the tableview. I assigned `identifier` and custom table view cell class with that prototype cell. Also created necessary outlets. Then this is my parent view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var theTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//        let cell = MyTableViewCell()
//        cell.optionText = UILabel()
//        cell.optionText?.text = "testing..."

//        theTableView.addSubview(cell)
        theTableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.optionText.text = "hello..."
        return cell
    }

}
```

But my table is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: You mean other than `theTableView.dataSource = self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following line in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
theTableView.dataSource = self
```

When you do that, you provide dataSource to your Tableview from your ViewController and then your TableView starts showing data.

The methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `rowsForSection` are both Datasource methods. Since you haven't set your dataSource that's why your TableView fails to load the provided data.

Also if you haven't added the TableView via Storyboard/Xib, you also have to add it as a subview of your view.